# Perforce: Undoing change from one revision automatically

Tags: git, perforce, perforce-integrate

Is there a way to undo a specific change in Perforce? i mean not just rolling back to certain revision...

For example, i have the file "test.txt" in revisions #10, #11, #12:

The revision #10 contains:
1
2
3

Revision #11 contains:
1
2
3
3

And Revision #12 contains:
1
2
3
3
4

My file is in revision #12, and i want to 'subtract' the revision #11, which added one more '3'.

From my knowledge, i would need to sync to a previous revision (#10), and then update my file to last revision and `resolve` it manually, in order to keep the changes made to #10 and #12.

I wonder if there is an automatic way to do that?
I know i can integrate a specifc change to a file like:

`p4 integrate //depot/v1/test.txt#11,#11 //depot/v2/test.txt`
 but what i want here is the opposite, i mean, subtract that specifc revision..

In CVS it was possible doing this way:
`cvs update -j (upper revision) -j (lower revision)`

And in Git:

`git.exe revert --no-edit --no-commit e5bf3a2cfc6edb4b7fa34233de458131d87e2d74`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this: [Backing Out Submitted Changelists](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists/)

That article is more general, and discusses more cases than yours, but the steps are still the same and work fine for your case.

Look in particular at the subsection entitled: Backing out an old changelist (edits only)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  
It still does not convince me though, there should be a command that would do these steps automatically, or even a replace (from the bad changes to '')... i dont know..  
It just seems too much work for a task that should be simple.
But the solution works for now, and that's what matters. Thank you!